# easyui Number formatting ,Drop down auto fill not working

Tags: jquery-easyui

```
<script type='text/javascript'>    
$('#tt').datagrid({ <br/>
        title:'',  <br/>
        iconCls:'icon-edit', <br/> 
        width:'fit-content',  <br/>
        height:'500',  <br/>
        singleSelect:true, <br/>
        idField:'id',  <br/>
        url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/tempexcess/', <br/>
    <br/><br/>
        toolbar:[{<br/>
                    text:'Add New',<br/>
                    iconCls:'icon-add',<br/>
                    <br/>
                handler:function(){<br/>
                    if($('#user_role').val()=='checker'){<br/>
                            alert('You don\'t have permission to do this operation !');<br/>
                        }<br/>
                        else if($('#user_role').val()=='maker'){ <br/>
                        insert();<br/>
                }<br/>
                }<br/>
<br/>
                }<br/>
            ],<br/>
        <br/>
        columns:[[ <br/>
         {field:'company_name',title:'Company Name',sortable:'true',<br/>
                  formatter:function(value){  <br/>
                        for(var i=0; i<company_namelist.length; i++){<br/>
                           if (company_namelist[i].company_name == value) return <br/>company_namelist[i].name;<br/>
                        }<br/>
                        return value;  <br/>
                    },  <br/>
                    editor:{  <br/>
                        type:'combobox',<br/>
                            options:{<br/>
                            valueField:'company_name',<br/>
                            textField:'name',<br/>
                            data:company_namelist,<br/>
                            required:true,<br/>
                                onSelect:function(record){<br/>
                                    <br/>
                            var row = $('#tt').datagrid('getSelected');<br/>
                            var rowIndex= $('#tt').datagrid('getRowIndex', row)<br/>
                var editors = $('#tt').datagrid('getEditors', rowIndex);<br/>
                            <br/>
                            var leidEditor = editors[0];<br/>
                            $(leidEditor.target).combobox('setValue',record.company_name); <br/>
                                      <br/>
                                }<br/>
                            } <br/>
                    }<br/>
                <br/>
            },<br/>
            {field:'amount',title:'Amount',groupSeparator:' <br/>',options:"precision:2,groupSeparator:' ',decimalSeparator:'.'" <br/>,sortable:'true',width:100,editor : <br/>
                       { type:'numberbox',<br/>
                                options:{<br/>
                                // precision:2 //,
                                 groupSeparator:','<br/>
                                <br/>
                                }<br/>
                                }<br/>
                        <br/>
            },  <br/>
        onBeforeEdit:function(index,row){  <br/>
            row.editing = true;  <br/>
            updateActions(index,row);  <br/>
        },  <br/>
        onAfterEdit:function(index,row){  <br/>
            row.editing = false;  <br/>
            updateActions(index,row);  <br/>
        },  <br/>
        onCancelEdit:function(index,row){  <br/>
            row.editing = false; <br/> 
            updateActions(index,row); <br/> 
        }    <br/>
            <br/>
        }); <br/>
</script><br/>
```

dtatgrid dropdowns when typing words autofill is not working, and number formatting is not working

Answer (score 0):

for the problem with the number formatting I found this solution:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>    
 $('#tt').datagrid({ 
 ...
 {field:'amount',title:'Amount',groupSeparator:,sortable:'true',width:100,
     formatter:function(value,row,index) {
       if(row.amount) {
         return number_format(value,2,',','.');
       }
     }
  }
 ...
}
 ...
function number_format(num,dig,dec,sep) {
  x=new Array();
  s=(num<0?"-":"");
  num=Math.abs(num).toFixed(dig).split(".");
  r=num[0].split("").reverse();
  for(var i=1;i<=r.length;i++){x.unshift(r[i-1]);if(i%3==0&&i!=r.length)x.unshift(sep);}
  return s+x.join("")+(num[1]?dec+num[1]:"");
}
...
 </script>
```

Comment: <script>{field:'outstanding_amount',title:'Outstanding       Amount',sortable:'true',width:150,      
                formatter:function(value){      
                    if(value>0){      
                        value =value.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");      
                      return value;       
                    }      
                       
                },      
                editor : 'text'      
            },</script>